# Hide non-coworkers from Hangouts search

Tags: google-hangouts

My company uses gmail for our work email. Frequently I accidentally open google hangouts with random strangers* - is there any way to just remove non-company people from the hangouts search entirely?

*Basically what happens is I type in the coworkers first name and press enter, because they're guaranteed to be the first entry to the search - but my mouse happens to be hovering over another search result. I don't understand why Google can display a handy little alert in the chat window that the person I'm chatting with doesn't have an email in the same domain, but they can't filter nonmatching domains from the search in the first place... -grumblegrumble-